# Is it possible to declare an array as constant

Tags: php

We can define a constant like

```
define("aconstant','avalue');
```

Can't we define array in this fashion like below ?

```
define("months",array("January", "February", ---);
```

Comment: You can somewhat convert an array to a string and store it as a constant. When you need it, you just reconvert it. Look into the (un)serialize example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290318/php-constants-containing-arrays

Comment: Yes, from PHP 5.6 on you can do this. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26470982/1163786

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**UPDATE:** this is possible in PHP 7 ([reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php))

```
// Works as of PHP 7
define('ANIMALS', array(
    'dog',
    'cat',
    'bird'
));
echo ANIMALS[1]; // outputs "cat"
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

From php.net...

> The value of the constant; only **scalar and null values are
>   allowed**. Scalar values are integer, float, string or boolean values.
>   It is possible to define resource constants, however it is not
>   recommended and may cause unpredictable behavior.

`$months = array("January,"February",...)` will be just fine.

Comment: Just in case anyone doesn't notice the other answer, you can create a "const" array in PHP 5.6 or newer.

Comment: Isn't `$months = array("January,"February",...)` missing a quotation mark?

Comment: Just to be clear, the PHP 7 introduction includes associative arrays too.  `define('MY_ANIMALS', array('dog' => 'Ottie', 'cat' => 'Garfield', 'bird'=>'Tweetie')); echo MY_ANIMALS['cat']; //outputs 'Garfield' `

Comment: Pre 7: `define('ANIMALS', json_encode( array('dog', 'cat', 'bird') ) );` Then when referencing: `json_decode(ANIMALS, true);`  Slightly inconvenient, but sometimes (like if you're storing the structure of your DB(s) for smarter querying inside a framework) it is much more worth it to do it this way than to make a call to the DB unnecessarily.

Comment: The same applies to to class constants in PHP 7.

Answer (score 80):

you can use **const** for that purpose since PHP 5.6 (via [nikic](https://twitter.com/nikita_ppv/status/524229344198402048)).

```
const months = ["January", "February"];
var_dump("January" === months[0]);
```

Comment: @cHao: Good one! ^^ Still, I love that it is possible in 5.6, and this de facto is the cleanest/perfect answer for 5.6 onwards. Even with 5.3 still being mainly used and 5.6 running on less than 1% of all php websites, this deserves more than 1 upvote, just for pointing out the existence of that feature (and so that many years from now, when those versions are more standard, this doesn't sit at 1 upvote, while the recommendation to use a variable has over 200 upvotes + accepted). Sry the rant, I actually really like your comment! ^^

Comment: To clarify, this is only possible within a class?

Answer (score 29):

You can put arrays inside constants with a hack:

```
define('MONTHS', serialize(array('January', 'February' ...)));
```

But then you have to [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize) that constant value when needed and I guess this isn't really that useful.

As an alternative, define multiple constants:

```
define('MONTH_1', 'January');
define('MONTH_2', 'February');
...
```

And use [`constant()`](http://php.net/constant) function to look up the value:

```
echo constant('MONTH_'.$month);
```

Comment: +1, but I wonder , what about json_encode and json_decode? which one is better for memory and performance?

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw: `serialize` would be better in most cases.  Even if it ended up being a little slower (which i'd guess is the opposite of the truth), it natively supports PHP concepts like references and typed objects, which would not survive a round trip through JSON.

Comment: @cHao, yes serialize is faster, but it's also dangerous as it might execute code. Even if here this doesn't apply, I think a security aware developer should get used to using the least dangerous methods. In this case, the performance difference is negligible and I think the JSON methods are better here.

Comment: @MarioAwad: In this case, security is not an issue -- constants are defined by the programmer, not the user.  I wouldn't `unserialize($input)`, but i certainly wouldn't be worried about a string that i wrote and that by definition won't have been tampered with.

Comment: @cHao you're definitely right and I already stated that here in this case this doesn't apply. Still, I think we should get used to using the least dangerous methods.

Comment: @MarioAwad: We shouldn't get used to blindly using the "least dangerous" methods; that way lies cargo cultism.  We should get used to *evaluating the dangers*.  Frankly, for purely internal stuff, the security risks associated with user input simply don't exist.  The greater danger is that what you get out might not be what you put in, and JSON can be pretty bad about that sometimes.  (Try `json_encode`ing anything that refers back to itself.)  I'll grant that `explode` would be simpler in this case. But JSON is overkill (and codewise, allows for unintended data structures to be passed in).

Comment: @cHao thank you for the clarifications and excellent points. I'm sure this discussion will be helpful as a future reference. Cheers.

Comment: @halilpazarlama http://tinyurl.com/serializespeed It would appear json_encode is much faster. Found: http://www.niden.net/2011/11/fast-serialization-of-data-in-php-how.html

Answer (score 11):

No, you can't. See [**PHP: Syntax - Manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php)

> Only **scalar data** (*boolean, integer, float* and *string*) can be contained in constants. 
>   It is possible to define constants as a resource, but it should be avoided, 
>   as it can cause unexpected results.

Comment: +1 I wonder why PHP allows defining constant resources in the first place?

Comment: @BoltClock's a Unicorn: I don't know exactly, have never come across the explanation. But given the development history of php it wouldn't surprise it is because of some 'historic reasons'.. :)

Answer (score 10):

You can use JSON format to keep array in string and then assign this string to constant.

```
$months = array("January","February","March");
define('MONTHS', json_encode($months));
```

When you want to use it:

```
$months = json_decode(MONTHS);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you must have a constant, how about using a a delimited string and exploding into an array?

```
define("MONTHS", "January;February;March");
$months = explode(";",MONTHS);
```

Comment: Not a bad option, I'd be curious to see the performance vs serialization.

Comment: I imagine it would take a large array to actually have a significant difference.

Answer (score 6):

As of PHP 5.6, it is possible [to declare constant arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php). The linked documentation uses the example `const ARR = ['a', 'b'];`. You could also do `const ARR = array('a', 'b');`. However, in 5.6 there is an odd quirk: you can declare constant arrays using `const`, but not `define()`. This [has been corrected](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/0833fd4619978c0522056b44dd53cd3b9d974cdd) in PHP 7.0.