# PHP - use array as class constant

Tags: php, arrays, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to declare an array as constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803349/is-it-possible-to-declare-an-array-as-constant)

Is it possible to use an array as a class constant in [PHP](http://www.php.net/)?

I.e

```
const MYARRAY = array('123', '234');
```

If not why?

Comment: [please use the search function before asking questions. we expect you to do research.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice)

Comment: The duplicate discussed constants created using define(). Rules for class constants are not the same. Voting to reopen.

Comment: You can somewhat convert an array to a string and store it as a constant. When you need it, you just reconvert it. Look into the (un)serialize example:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290318/php-constants-containing-arrays

Comment: @Jack, I agree because I find a way to do what I need (xdazz answer) thanks to this question - we aren't only interested in answer like "No, it isn't posibble", but in that which tells us how to do what we want.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

UPDATE:

This is now available in PHP 5.6 https://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php

---

No you can't assign an Array to PHP constant.

In http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php

> Constants may only evaluate to scalar values

This is the reason.

Scalar values for examples are `int`, `float`, `string`

Comment: Short but clear, and still perfectly explained, thanks!

Comment: This is now available in PHP 5.6
http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php

Answer (score 77):

No, you can't.

But you could declare it as a static property.

```
public static $MYARRAY = array('123', '234');
```

*---------------Update-----------------------------*

**Array const is available from PHP 5.6.**

[php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php)

Comment: This wouldn't be the same as a constant though as the value could be changed

Comment: @Martin Yep, that's true, but you can not declare a constant with an array.

Comment: Can a static be declared private at least?

Comment: @Martin Furthermore, you can declare a public getter if you wanted something like a public constant.

Comment: Then I got this `Strict Standards: Accessing static property `