# array of floats use in php

Tags: php, arrays

In order to draw my chart, I need to have 2 arrays of floats,

1. The first one stores in MySQL database as a type of string (separated by commas)
2. And I want to define the second one as a constant array (in PHP)

my problem is how to change the type of data as string(MySQL) and use it as arrays of float in PHP.
Also, how should I define the second array? Should I change it to string and then use unserialize?

This just print 1

```
$data = array();
$data['cols'] = array(
    array('id' => 'Signal','label' => 'Signal', 'type' => 'string'));

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $temp = array();
  $temp[] = array('v' => $r['Signal']); 
  $res = array_map("floatval", $temp);

  var_dump($res);}                                 

echo var_dump($res);
```

Comment: What does your data look like in MySQL.

Comment: @slapyo, actually these are signals. like this: 0.0,
2.0545915E-5,
4.108994E-5,
6.16302E-5,

Comment: If you use a 'string' containing a 'floating point representation' in a 'calculation' involving 'floating point' numbers then PHP will convert the 'string' to a 'floating point' number first and then do the calculation accordingly. i.e. '3.14' * 1.0 will result in a floating point value. PHP uses the 'arithmetic context' to 'know' that strings values need to be converted to 'numbers'. i.e. you don't often need to convert explicitly to a 'number' type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [floatval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) and [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to parse your string array into a float array.

A simple tested example:

```
$input_array = Array("1.1234", "3.123", "2.23E3", "2.23E-3");

$result = array_map("floatval", $input_array);

var_dump($input_array);
var_dump($result);
```

Prints:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=> string(6) "1.1234"
  [1]=> string(5) "3.123"
  [2]=> string(6) "2.23E3"
  [3]=> string(7) "2.23E-3"
}
array(4) {
  [0]=> float(1.1234)
  [1]=> float(3.123)
  [2]=> float(2230)
  [3]=> float(0.00223)
}
```

P.S.: If your database result is somewhat more structured than just a flat array of float-valued strings, you might need to do more than just map it. Provide some more info on what you have and what you expect for more detailed help.

---

As for your second array, I'm afraid you can't mark arrays as constant. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129066/php-const-arrays) is a relevant question. You can go into classes and [autosetters](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set), but I'm not sure that kind of complexity is justified for your requirements.

Comment: is it possible to explain more about floatval() and array_map?

Comment: @nazanin Certainly. Take a look at the linked docs first and let me know what is confusing. I need to at least see an example of your input data and know more about what you would like to see as a result. The more details - the better. Until then any more details might just go the wrong way and be confusing.

Comment: @nazanin Updated with quite a bit more additional research. See if this answers your question and let me know if I can help more.

Comment: thank you for the comments, but my data store like ( 0.0, 2.0545915E-5, 4.108994E-5, 6.16302E-5,) without quotations, just its type is string in MySQL. when I use $result = array_map("floatval", $input_array); it print 1 as result. sorry I don't know much in PHP