# PHP: Does it make sense to create constant arrays to increase performance?

Tags: php, arrays, optimization, constants

I need to perform many `str_replace($search, $replace, $input)` using the same `$search` and `$replace`. These are exploded in a function:

```
function sr($input) {

    $search = explode(",","s1,s2,s3,....");
    $replace = explode(",","r1,r2,r3,...");

    return str_replace($search, $replace, $input);

}
```

It is not very efficient. From another SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290318/php-constants-containing-arrays), I see that I could create constant arrays, but the suggested method implies serialization. I bet this is not efficient too, but am I right?

I have a compiled language *mindset*, so whenever I can make something constant, I am happy. But does it make sense in PHP? I am not a PHP pro.

More precisely, knowing that this function is going to be used when users make web requests to a page, how can I optimize explodes efficiently? Is there any such thing as precompiled code in PHP? Or can I define constant arrays once for all, efficiently (like testing whether the constant is already created/available in the context)?

**UPDATE**

Taking Truth's suggestion into account, we can modify the function as following:

```
function sr($input) {

    $search = array("s1","s2","s3",....");
    $replace = array("r1","r2","r3",...");

    return str_replace($search, $replace, $input);

}
```

The remaining question is: is it optimal to declare these arrays at each call or could should we try to create them as constants in the context?

Comment: There are PHP compilers, but not all PHP scripts can be compiled.

Comment: I don't see the point of explode. Why don't you just set `$search = array("s1", "s2", "s3", ....);`?

Comment: @Truth Yes you have point, I just lack experience in PHP. I am updating my question

Comment: You could use `static` keyword for that purpose, but I have any info if it would have impact on performance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does it make sense to [take random action right off your head] to increase performance?

### No.

1. Start worrying about performance only if you have certain performance problem.
2. Once you've got it - start *profiling*.
3. Once you've got certain profiling results pointing to certain bottleneck - start optimizing that bottleneck.
4. Repeat until done.

Comment: Assuming we hit a bottleneck, how would you answer my question?

Comment: What he means is you can't think about optimization if you don't understand where the performance problem is - and if it really exists.

Comment: @JVerstry easy-peasy. I'd avoid performing many str_replace on each user's request.