# in_array does not work with class constants

Tags: php, arrays, class, constants

I have a problem with in_array using newly introduced array class constants. When I put a class constant which contains an array into the function I get a warning:

```
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, unknown given in...
```

**Code:**

```
foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($key, self::FIELDS)) $this->$key = $value;
}
```

**Constant (inside a class):**

```
const FIELDS = [
    self::FIELD_ID,
    self::FIELD_STREET,
    self::FIELD_HOUSE_NR,
    self::FIELD_POSTCODE,
    self::FIELD_CITY,
    self::FIELD_PERSONAL_NUMBER,
    self::FIELD_SELLER_NAME,
    'empty'
];
```

The weirdest part of this problem is that it works on my local machine without any errors/warnings (Mac) running PHP 5.6.2 but does not on my server also running PHP 5.6.2.

How do I resolve this error? (I don't want to use static arrays...)

Comment: what is the self::FIELDS

Comment: Obviously self::FIELDS is not what you think it should be, can you dump it ?

Comment: On my local machine, self::FIELDS is an array containing 8 strings (like it should be). On my server it is "UNKNOWN:0".

Comment: in that case the posted code isn't relevant.

Comment: I added the constant definition to my post.

Answer (score 0):

The root problem is class constants can't be arrays (unless it's php 5.6 or greater as pointed out by bluefirex).
[PHP Constants Containing Arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290318/php-constants-containing-arrays)
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Comment: Of course! Since PHP 5.6 this is a feature. It does work on my local machine as expected - just not on the server.

Answer (score 0):

On PHP 7.2 and in_array returned `FALSE` with a class constant array, at least in my case...

I used this as a workaround:

```
if(isset(self::MAPPING_OLD_REFS[$sku]))  $sku = self::MAPPING_OLD_REFS[$sku];
```