# Can we define constant array in Codeigniter.?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Currently I can able to create constant variable in Codeigniter, but is there any way to create constant array in CI. Suppose I can create constant array of Languages supported by my website.

```
$language = array('English', 'French');
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290318/php-constants-containing-arrays/27413238#27413238

Comment: it's not related to codeignter, constant arrays is related to php syntax it self, and YES, as long as your php version is higher than 5.6 you can use constant array http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php

Answer (score 4):

In your constants.php located in your application/config folder simply declare it as

```
defined('LANGUAGE') OR define('LANGUAGE', array('English', 'French'));
```

Use can use them as

```
foreach (LANGUAGE as $key => $value) {
  echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in your `config->constants.php`

```
$config['language'] = 'english';
$config['language'] = 'french';
```