# How to set a variable to constant defined using "const" keyword?

Tags: php, laravel, constants

I need to store an `array` to a constant. I am using **PHP 5.6**, so cant use `define`. I am getting that data from database.

It is working for -

```
const VAR_DATA = array(1, 2, 3);
```

But when I do -

```
$var = array(1, 2, 3);
const VAR_DATA = $var;
```

It is giving me syntax error.

How can I achieve that?

Not duplicate as That question dose not answer how to achieve this. For regular arrays it is working but when I am using a variable it is giving me the error.

Comment: Can't use `define`? Why?

Comment: `define` can be used for this on PHP 7 and onwards. Not supported on 5.5. @u_mulder. `define` doesnot support string arrays on 5.6

Comment: So, the answer is that you cannot achieve what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Constants Containing Arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290318/php-constants-containing-arrays)

Comment: @u_mulder I am looking for an workaround if not possible. Trying to avoid `serialize` or other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save array like this

```
define('VAR_DATA', implode(',',array(1, 2, 3)));
```

And wherever you want to use it, just explode it by

```
$array = explode(',',VAR_DATA);
```

Answer (score 1):

The value must be a constant expression, **not (for example) a variable**, a property, or a function call.see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

and you can define a constant with const like this ,const SOMEVAR = [1,2,4]

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: try this ,const SOMEVAR = [1,2,4] or const SOMEVAR = array(1,2,4) @sougata bose

Answer (score 1):

from [Document](http://php.net/define)

In **PHP 5**, value must be a scalar value (integer, float, string, boolean, or NULL)

Objects and Arrays cannot be stored in constants without serializing them first

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your const is declared in a class (called VarClass below), you could have public static access instead of a const:

```
class VarClass
{
    public static function VAR_DATA()
    {
        return $your_data_here;
    }
}
```

or even

```
class VarClass 
{
    public static $VAR_DATA;
}
```

and set it once you retrieved it from the database:

```
VarClass::$VAR_DATA = $your_data;
```

and then get it:

```
$get_data = VarClass::$VAR_DATA;
```

> I am getting that data from database.

If you get the data array from the database, then why do you consider it to be a const? Apparently, it comes into existence at some point in your code execution. From there on you want to treat it as immutabel data.

The solution above solves the access problem, but does not solve the immutability. Using a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) could help with that, but might be overkill in your scenario.

Comment: That array will be used multiple times, in multiple classes, in multiple functions. I want to avoid that changes in function calls and all. If I could define the constant in middleware or something that constant would be present and accessed without changing function calls

Comment: *The solution above solves the access problem, but does not solve the immutability. Using a Singleton could help with that, but might be overkill in your scenario.* Yup..

Comment: So you basically have legacy code that uses the VAR_DATA const, but it actually is no longer a const, as meanwhile the data is to be fetched from the database. However, you don't want to chenge the legacy code?

Comment: Yup. Kind of that. Now I am going to use `serialize` for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can do one trick save your data in .env like this

## .env file

```
VARIABLE_NAME=Value1,Value2,Value3
```

## config/app.php

```
return [
  'VARIABLE_NAME' => explode(',', env('VARIABLE_NAME'))
];
```

hope it will solve your prob