# Calling a constant?

Tags: php, php-7

I define a constant with:

```
const NAMES = [
    'boys' => 'john',
    'girls' => 'sue',
];
```

I try and then call the constant later with:

```
NAMES['boys']
```

But get the error:

```
"Use of undefined constant NAMES - assumed 'NAMES'"
```

Why is this happening?

EDIT:

It's on a class with PHP7

Comment: @Carcigenicate Constant !== Variable

Comment: what php version do you use? if its < 5.6 then constants can't contain arrays. [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290318/php-constants-containing-arrays)

Comment: @panthro Is this defined inside a class? Or just as a constant in the global namespace?

Comment: [works for me](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bdba2c405a1f74260b9b3ccd3ee9908c78124d38)

Comment: In fact it only fails on hhvm-3.18.5 according to https://3v4l.org/TUa3f

Comment: It's on a class with PHP7

Comment: Arrays as constants were added in 5.6, but this would raise a different error on earlier versions (a parse error, etc). This will only show up if the constant is in a different scope, e.g. in a class/namespace.

Comment: can you post the code? Perhaps it is really not defined at the time you are using it.

Comment: If its in a class, then you need the appropriate `$this->` or `self::` in front of using it (assuming you are calling it within the class). Or `$obj->` and `Classname::` if outside respectively.

Comment: Being in a class means you have to reference it via its fully qualified name e.g. `ClassName::NAMES["boys"]` (or `self::` from within the class). Actually you always have to reference it by its fully qualified name but in the global scope that's just the name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't reference a class constant without prefixing it with either the class name (or with `self` from within the same class):

```
<?php
class Foo
{
  const NAMES = [
    'boys' => 'john',
    'girls' => 'sue',
  ];
}

echo Foo::NAMES['boys']; // John
```

Only constants in global scope can be referenced using just their name.