# How to check if constant array item exists

Tags: php, constants

I'm working on a project where I assign my URI list to a constant array.

```
$vars = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
array_shift($vars);
if(end($vars) == "" && count($vars) > 0){ //remove last element when empty (occures when using / at the end of URL)
    array_pop($vars);
}
define("URI_VARS", $vars);
unset($vars);
```

The big question is, how can I check if an item exists? If I use `defined("URI_VARS")`, it of course works, but how can I check for instance does `URI_VARS[1]` exist?

`defined("URI_VARS[1]")` seems not to work. I found something online about `defined("URI_VARS", "1")` or `defined("URI_VARS" , 1)` but both are not working.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `defined("URI_VARS") or define("URI_VARS", $vars);` will check if is defined, if not, define with `$vars`. Is that what you want?

Comment: If you remove leading and trailing `/` using `trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')`, you won't need your `if` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defined()` only takes one argument, so `defined("URI_VARS" , 1)` isn't a valid call. You'll get a warning and it will return null instead of true or false. You just need to add a second check to verify that the key exists after checking that the constant is defined.

```
$check = defined("URI_VARS") && array_key_exists(1, URI_VARS);
```

The second part (`array_key_exists(1, URI_VARS)`) won't be evaluated if the first part returns false, so you don't need to worry about undefined constant warnings.

Answer (score 0):

As @Don't Panic mentioned, you can use `array_key_exists` to check for the existence of the key you're looking for. If you don't know the specific key, or just want to check to see if you have a certain amount of URI segments, you could use `count` http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

```
if (defined('URI_VARS') && count(URI_VARS) >= 2) {
   // do something
}
```

Also, be careful about declaring an constants as an array, as the behavior has changed over time. [PHP Constants Containing Arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290318/php-constants-containing-arrays/27413238#27413238)