# Hhvm : Arrays are not allowed in class constants

Tags: php, arrays, constants, hhvm

I've a php script that runs ok on my local (MAC High Sierra 10.13.6, php version 7.1.16) using `php file.php ...`

`hhvm --version` gives `HipHop VM 3.11.0 (rel)`

When I run from vagrant (hhvm), it complains `Fatal error: Arrays are not allowed in class constants in certainfile.php on line xxx`. using `hhvm file.php ...`.

In my file, I've a const defined as:

`class Lalala {
       const AB_C = array(A::a, B::b,...);
       function xyz {...use self::AB_C ...}
}`

I tried to change it to 
`define("AB_C", array(A::a, B::b,...));`, but it couldn't even compile with syntax error.

How should I declare the constant arrays here please? 
Thank you.

---

`define("AB_C", serialize(array(A::a, B::b,...)));`also failed with same syntax error

`define("AB_C", jsonencode(array(A::a, B::b,...)));`also failed with same syntax error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Constants Containing Arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290318/php-constants-containing-arrays)

Comment: HHVM seems to be more restrictive. Is there any reason you have to use HHVM? I got away from HHVM since PHP7.

Comment: `define("AB_C", serialize(array(A::a, B::b,...)));` cannot work since `serialize` is a runtime function but HHVM is compiled. You would need preprocessing to evaluate this expression running PHP. Same with `jsonencode`

Answer (score 3):

You can't use arrays as class constants until I believe 3.19, I know it works as of HHVM 3.19.2 but could have been a little bit earlier.  If you update HHVM to the latest (or at least a more recent) version, it will work.

https://hhvm.com/blog/2017/04/13/hhvm-3-19.html

> Noteworthy changes include:
>
> Const Array support.

Comment: 3.11 https://3v4l.org/jE8Et edit: ye you right :) 3.19 ... brain lag :D

Comment: Corollary: please don't use old and unsupported versions of HHVM. Version 3.11 is several years old -- I'm not sure how you even got a copy. https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/installation/release-schedule details the release schedule and supported versions.