# replacement of array define in php 5.6

Tags: php, wordpress, constants

on my localhost `PHP7` is running and I am using `define()` function to define an array. It's working fine.

```
define('JOBS_CREATORS', ['aaa@admin.com', 'bbbb@admin.com']);
```

As we know it works in `PHP7` version. I googled and found `const` keyword which works in `PHP5.6` or lower version.

As I know the `const` works only within the `class`.

But I am using WordPress so I need to define in `functions.php` file.

Is there any other way to define an array without using `class`?

Comment: If your hosting provider is still on PHP 5.6, you need to think about finding a new one. Even PHP 7.0 is old enough that it's out of support now and considered end-of-life.

Comment: Actually, there are other PHP sites are running and they require PHP lower version. That's why I can't upgrade the PHP version.

Comment: Fix the other sites so they don't depend on unsupported versions of PHP which don't get security fixes!

Comment: This is also why platforms like Docker are so good. With Docker you can run each of your systems in its own isolated container, so they can all run the version of PHP (or whatever) that they need, without interfering with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your constant to accept a serialized array instead.

```
define('JOBS_CREATORS', serialize(['aaa@admin.com', 'bbbb@admin.com']));
```

then

```
if(in_array("aaa@admin.com", unserialize(JOBS_CREATORS))){ ...
```

Comment: if you're going to do that, use `json_encode` rather than `serialize`.

Comment: @Spudley, serialize is working fine. Is there any different to json_encode instead of serializing?

Comment: Serialize is overweight and overcomplex (and occasionally prone to security holes). The only correct use-case for it is if you're using the sleep/wakeup functionality for persisting an object between runs.

Comment: Thanks @Spudley for help :)

Comment: @GufranHasan The main point was serializing the data, no matter how you do it. `json_encode` is also a form of serialization. BTW, wordpress still uses `serialize` for saving data into database.

Answer (score 0):

It is still possible to do this in PHP 5.6 using the `const` keyword (see in this post):

[PHP Constants Containing Arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290318/php-constants-containing-arrays)

```
const JOBS_CREATORS = ['aaa@admin.com', 'bbbb@admin.com'];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried it but unfortunately, it's not worked.it' gives error const value cannot update.

Comment: can you show me your code? Of course you cannot UPDATE a constant... that is why it is called a constant. If you need to update it, you have to use a variable instead of a constant

Answer (score 0):

As **@Spudley** suggested that use `json_encode` rather than `serialize`. I have used `json_encode` and `json_decode` as:

**Defined:**

```
define('JOBS_CREATORS', json_encode(['aaa@admin.com', 'bbbb@admin.com']));
```

**Getting:**

```
echo '<pre>';print_r(json_decode(JOBS_CREATORS)); echo '</pre>';
```

But **@TahaPaksu**'s answer is also useful.

Thanks, **@Spudley** and **@TahaPaksu** :)